# Can I Feign clients ConnectTimeout & ReadTimeout override using Ribbon configuration?

Tags: spring-cloud, ribbon, hystrix, feign

First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English.

Can I Feign clients ConnectTimeout & ReadTimeout override using Ribbon configuration?

I don't know how to set 'Feign.client.ReadTimeout' with 'ribbon.readTimeout'.

Below are the relevant my settings.

```yml
<serviceId>:
  ribbon:
    ConnectTimeout: 100
    ReadTimeout: 500
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 0

feign:
  client:
    config:
      <commandKey>:
        connectTimeout: 100
        readTimeout: 500
```

I hope you give an answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spring boot configuration replacements.

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      <commandKey>:
        connectTimeout: ${<serviceId>.ribbon.ConnectTimeout:100}
        readTimeout: ${<serviceId>.ribbon.ReadTimeout:500}
```